# Rounded corners with border-radius only affecting one side

Tags: html, css, svg, polygon

I'm trying to recreate this:

[image: This is I want to do]

I am using SVG and Polygon, is there any way more easy to do this and fix the border-radius?

```html
<div class="showCaseVideo" style="background: none;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" style="border-top-left-radius: 300px 70px; border-bottom-left-radius: 300px 70px; border-radius: 35px;">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
   <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#076FAD;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#28AADD;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <polygon points="0,10 100,0 100,100 0,90" style="/*! display: none; *//*! color: white; *//*! stroke: white; */fill: url(#grad1);/*! display: M64.5 45.5 82.5 45.5 82.5 64.5 64.5 64.5 z; */" d="M64.5 45.5 82.5 45.5 82.5 64.5 64.5 64.5 z">
 </polygon>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide proper detail or jsfiddle

Comment: Edited (I add jsfiddle to explain what I have)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a pseudo element with a 3d transform.

```css
.slanted {
  position: relative;
  perspective: 500px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 120px;
  z-index: 1;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2.4;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  
}

.slanted::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: cornflowerblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transform: rotateY(-20deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="slanted">
  Slanted
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens is you round the corners of the svg element not the corners of the polygon. In the next example I've recalculated your polygon to a path with rounded corners by adding quadratic Béziers for the corners. I hope it helps.

```css
svg{width:90vh}
```

```html
<div class="showCaseVideo" style="background: none;">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none" >
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
   <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#076FAD;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#28AADD;stop-opacity:1"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <!--<polygon points="0,10 100,0 100,100 0,90" style="fill: url(#grad1);">
  </polygon>-->
    
    <path style="fill: url(#grad1);" d="M6.123233995736766e-16,20 Q0,10 9.950371902099892,9.00496280979001L90.04962809790011,0.9950371902099887 Q100,0 100,10L100,90 Q100,100 90.04962809790011,99.00496280979002L9.950371902099892,90.99503719020998 Q0,90 6.123233995736766e-16,80Z" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Another option would be using an HTML element with rounded corners and rotate it using `perspective`, `transform-style: preserve-3d;` and `transform: rotateY()`.

In this second case the text would be transformed as well.